# How to make a count for each day passed from start date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm looking for a way to count each day passed from a start date in python. So if the start date was 21/02/2020 and count equals to 0, when the next day starts count should increment by 1.

Edit: After using Rusty's code I am able to show you a minimal reproducible example.

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(input("Choose a start date (mm/dd/yyyy): "), '%m/%d/%Y')

current = datetime.datetime.now()

delta = current - start
count = delta.days

print(count)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @IMCoins, I'm not good at manipulating and using the datetime module and so I never found a way that is close at all.

Comment: When I see your other comment on the answer from Rusty, it looks like you know how to use the `datetime` module. You should show us a [mcve]. My guess would be that you need a class, and in the `__init__`, begin a counter, and then, make a method that displays the current difference with the date that has been previously initiated.

Comment: @IMCoins, Im familiar with Rusty's answer because wherever I searched for an answer the only available response was to find the difference between two dates. After reading your comment now I realized that I could get the count by getting the difference between the start date and current date, however I want a way that when the current date changes it automatically gets the difference with the start date and the new current date. Im sorry but I dont have any code that I can show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
import time

count = 0

# "...from today..."
today = datetime.datetime.today()

# "...to infinity..."
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.today()

    # "...as soon as the next day starts..."
    if today.day != now.day:
        # "...it would increment count by 1..."
        count = count + 1
        print(count)
        today = now
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you Rusty Widebottom, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I would also like to know what the line: `time.sleep(1)` does.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime
today    = datetime.datetime.strptime('03/21/2020', '%m/%d/%Y')
tomorrow = datetime.datetime.strptime('03/22/2020', '%m/%d/%Y')
next_saturday = datetime.datetime.strptime('03/28/2020', '%m/%d/%Y')

delta = tomorrow - today
count = delta.days
print(count)

delta = next_saturday - today
count = delta.days
print(count)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly trying to find a way to get the count between two dates, rather the count for each day passing by from a start date. So if today is 22/03/2020, then as soon as the next day starts from today to infinity it would increment count by 1. Hope that makes sense.